# SQL Server 2008 - UPDATE never finish

Tags: sql-server-2008, timeout

I have this very simple query in my database in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
UPDATE  Table1
   SET  Field1  = 'This value'
 WHERE  ID      = '12345'
```

I tried to execute this query and I never get successful results. First, it executes for a really long time. One time I executed this query and left it there while I take my lunch. When I came back 2 hours later, it still isn't finished.

I need to execute this query programatically. I have everything needed to execute it there but the only problem now is that it gives me a "Timeout" error message. I tried increasing my CommandTimeOut but doing so will just hold the program for a longer time. (Since executing the query in SQL Server really takes a long time, please see my scenario earlier)

Can someone please point me to a good solution to avoid this problem? And yes, the table I am accessing has a lot of records like thousands. This has never been a problem before but now it is. :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Two questions: (1) is there an **index** on the `ID` column?? And (2) - what datatype is `ID` ?? If it's a numeric datatype, you shouldn't use a string to specify your ID - use `WHERE ID = 12345` (without the quotes) instead. And PS: *thousands* of rows is **NOTHING** - if we're talking several hundred million - then we have "lots" ....

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to change? Have you looked at SQL profiler? Have you run similar queries (`where id='23456'`)?

Comment: "a lot of records like thousands. " - that is a very small number of rows.  To put it into perspective, 100 millions is reasonably large..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you left open a transaction that locked the row with ID 12345. The command will *never* finish until you commit or rollback that transaction.

Open the [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and see what transaction is blocking your update. Then locate the SSMS window left uncommitted from which you've run this transaction and commit or rollback.

For more details see [Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453). For general performance troubleshooting methodology see [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx).

Comment: +100000. This is just what I needed. Apparently, a few other SELECT statements locked the same row. Thank you very much! This reminded me of the `WITH(NOLOCK) keyword.